# TypeError: msg.trim is not a function in Ionic project

Tags: ionic-framework

I am trying to start my first Ionic project following theses steps : [Ionic framework get started page](https://ionicframework.com/getting-started/)

But when I am writing in the terminal `ionic serve` (step 3) I have got this error message even if I run the Development server at http://localhost:8100 (my app is running but I still got this error message):

```
TypeError: msg.trim is not a function
at Logger.log (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/@ionic/cli-utils/lib/utils/logger.js:78:21)
at Logger.error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/@ionic/cli-utils/lib/utils/logger.js:35:14)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/dist/index.js:261:22)
at throw (native)
at rejected (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:94:69)
```

Also during the setup when I write the command sudo ionic start myApp tabs I have got this : `Running command - failed! [ERROR] An error occurred while running npm install (exit code 1):`

Complete Error message in the the terminal (I am on macOS) is:

```
    npm WARN deprecated babili@0.1.2: babili has been renamed to 
    babel-minify. Please update to babel-minify
    npm WARN deprecated babel-preset-babili@0.1.4: babili has been renamed 
    to babel-minify. Please update to babel-preset-minify
    npm WARN deprecated object-keys@0.2.0: Please update to the latest 
    object-keys

    > fsevents@1.1.2 install 
    /Users/emilio/TestIonic/myApp/node_modules/fsevents
    > node install

    [fsevents] Success: 
    "/Users/emilio/TestIonic/myApp/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v48-darwin-x64/fse.node" 
    already installed
    Pass --update-binary to reinstall or --build-from-source to recompile

    > node-sass@4.5.3 install 
    /Users/emilio/TestIonic/myApp/node_modules/node-sass
    > node scripts/install.js

    Unable to save binary 
    /Users/emilio/TestIonic/myApp/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/darwin-x64-48 
    : { Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir 
    '/Users/emilio/TestIonic/myApp/node_modules/node-sass/vendor'
         at Error (native)
         at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:924:18)
         at sync 
    (/Users/emilio/TestIonic/myApp/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:71:13)
         at Function.sync 
    (/Users/emilio/TestIonic/myApp/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:77:24)
         at checkAndDownloadBinary 
    (/Users/emilio/TestIonic/myApp/node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js:111:11)
         at Object.<anonymous> 
    (/Users/emilio/TestIonic/myApp/node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js:154:1)
         at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
         at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
         at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
         at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
       errno: -13,
       code: 'EACCES',
       syscall: 'mkdir',
       path: '/Users/emilio/TestIonic/myApp/node_modules/node-sass/vendor' }

    > uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall 
    /Users/emilio/TestIonic/myApp/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
    > node lib/post_install.js


    > node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall 
    /Users/emilio/TestIonic/myApp/node_modules/node-sass
    > node scripts/build.js

    Building: /usr/local/bin/node 
    /Users/emilio/TestIonic/myApp/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js 
    rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= 
    --libsass_library=
    gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
    gyp verb cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node',
    gyp verb cli   
    '/Users/emilio/TestIonic/myApp/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
    gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
    gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
    gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
    gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
    gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
    gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library=' ]
    gyp info using node-gyp@3.6.2
    gyp info using node@6.11.3 | darwin | x64
    gyp verb command rebuild []
    gyp verb command clean []
    gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
    gyp verb command configure []
    gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the 
    PATH
    gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
    gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError 
    (/Users/emilio/TestIonic/myApp/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at F 
    (/Users/emilio/TestIonic/myApp/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at E 
    (/Users/emilio/TestIonic/myApp/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at 
    /Users/emilio/TestIonic/myApp/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
    gyp verb `which` failed     at 
    /Users/emilio/TestIonic/myApp/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
    gyp verb `which` failed     at 
    /Users/emilio/TestIonic/myApp/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
    gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
    gyp verb `which` failed  python2 { Error: not found: python2
    gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError 
    (/Users/emilio/TestIonic/myApp/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at F 
    (/Users/emilio/TestIonic/myApp/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at E 
    (/Users/emilio/TestIonic/myApp/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at 
    /Users/emilio/TestIonic/myApp/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
    gyp verb `which` failed     at 
    /Users/emilio/TestIonic/myApp/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
    gyp verb `which` failed     at 
    /Users/emilio/TestIonic/myApp/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
    gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
    gyp verb `which` failed   stack: 'Error: not found: python2\n    at 
    getNotFoundError 
    (/Users/emilio/TestIonic/myApp/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)\n    
    at F (/Users/emilio/TestIonic/myApp/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)\n 
       at E 
    (/Users/emilio/TestIonic/myApp/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)\n    
    at /Users/emilio/TestIonic/myApp/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16\n    
    at /Users/emilio/TestIonic/myApp/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5\n    
    at /Users/emilio/TestIonic/myApp/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5\n    at 
    FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)',
    gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT' }
    gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the 
    PATH
    gyp verb `which` succeeded python /usr/bin/python
    gyp verb check python version `/usr/bin/python -c "import platform; 
    print(platform.python_version());"` returned: "2.7.10\n"
    gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to 
    host node version: 6.11.3
    gyp verb command install [ '6.11.3' ]
    gyp verb install input version string "6.11.3"
    gyp verb install installing version: 6.11.3
    gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already 
    installed
    gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check 
    "installVersion"
    gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
    gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
    gyp verb install version is good
    gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 6.11.3
    gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: 
    /Users/emilio/TestIonic/myApp/node_modules/node-sass/build
    gyp ERR! configure error 
    gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir 
    '/Users/emilio/TestIonic/myApp/node_modules/node-sass/build'
    gyp ERR! stack     at Error (native)
    gyp ERR! System Darwin 16.7.0
    gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" 
    "/Users/emilio/TestIonic/myApp/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" 
    "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" 
    "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
    gyp ERR! cwd /Users/emilio/TestIonic/myApp/node_modules/node-sass
    gyp ERR! node -v v6.11.3
    gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
    gyp ERR! not ok 
    Build failed with error code: 1
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely 
    additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /Users/emilio/.npm/_logs/2017-09-25T08_05_30_711Z-debug.log
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to uninstall and install ionic, ionic cli

Comment: @Duannx I did so but it doesn't work.. during the setup when I write the command `sudo ionic start myApp tabs` I have got this : ` Running command - failed!
[ERROR] An error occurred while running npm install (exit code 1):
`==> I have updated my post according to this

Comment: Sorry i do not have any idea about that error. Make sure you uninstall and install ionic with -g (global) varible. Then re-install `object-keys` with -g. And run ionic command in folder with full read-write permission to avoid access denied error. If it still does not work, you should post your error in [forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/). There are many Ionic contributors ready to help you in there.

Comment: It seems you don't have permission to that folder. Try installing with sudo npm your command.

Comment: @HGK The strange thing is I put some `sudo` before each command line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this it [worked for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47133396/msg-trim-is-not-a-function). Having Ionic Pro helps as well

```
npm install ionic-angular@latest --save
npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

Please update npm to npm 3.x. You can follow the instructions here: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-node#updating-npm

Let me know if that fixes it for you!

Comment: @Narendra :-( still the same error for me TypeError: msg.trim is not a function
    ...also got 2 errors in my JS browser console: [Warning] Native: tried calling StatusBar.styleDefault, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator (vendor.js, line 56743)
[Warning] Native: tried calling SplashScreen.hide, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator (vendor.js, line 56743)

Comment: @EmileCantero
please try 'npm cache clean'

Comment: Please remove node_modules folder, uninstalling ionic global module and re-install again, and update npm

Answer (score 0):

Ionic version update to 3.7,
my problem solved