# TypeError: msg.trim is not a function in ionic

Tags: javascript, node.js, ionic-framework, ionic2

Please help me, cant get any solution from anywhere. Below is screenshot.
[image]

This answer does not work, so please dont refer:-
http://stackoverflow.com/a/46466176/5866781

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46466176/5866781

Comment: no it dont works

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error when I was running an ionic command as a user without root permissions (I initially had packages installed with the root user).

Does it work if you use the command with sudo? If so, the permissions for your user directory need changed so you can access the required files (with sudo chown -R yourusername ~/your-username/).